# How to make JFrame work in Full Screen Mode

Tags: java, fullscreen

How? I read about Exclusive Mode API and there is such code:

```
GraphicsDevice myDevice;
Window myWindow;

try {
    myDevice.setFullScreenWindow(myWindow);
    ...
} finally {
    myDevice.setFullScreenWindow(null);
}
```

But it doesn't work. Id like to set JFrame to full size. Could someone write me proper code to do this? It should be places in frame's constrcutor.

Comment: I would recommend you produce an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) which demonstrates the problem. That will help us to answer you, plus it might help you discover your error. Should only take 2 mins.

Answer (score 1):

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
frame.setUndecorated(true);
```